# Python save multiple images with pyautogui

Tags: python, multithreading, screenshot, pyautogui

Im making a screenshot program that takes a screenshot every 5 seconds. But it will only save 1 .png file. Its becuase the name is the same every time and it wont make duplicates.

How do i save them as image(1), image(2), image(3)....

This is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import threading

#myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
#myScreenshot.save(r'C:\Users\censored\Desktop\screenshot\imgs\image.png')


def ScreenShotTimer():
    threading.Timer(5.0, ScreenShotTimer).start()
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    myScreenshot.save(r'C:\Users\censored\Desktop\screenshot\imgs\image.png')
    print('Program Is Still Running.')

ScreenShotTimer()
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pyautogui

# Solution 1

import time

for i in range(60):
    ss = pyautogui.screenshot()

    ss.save(f"SS {i}.png")

    time.sleep(5)


# Solution 2

import threading
import functools as ft

def screenshot(index: int = 0):
    ss = pyautogui.screenshot()

    ss.save(f"SS {index}.png")

    threading.Timer(5.0, ft.partial(screenshot, index+1)).start()

screenshot()
```

Two solutions.

1. Uses a for loop (could easily be a while loop).
2. Uses `threading.Timer` and `functools.partial` to call the
       function again, with a different parameter.